# Are there any hamiltonian systems without a periodic orbit?

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism

Are there any hamiltonian systems without a periodic orbit? Can anyone give me an example?

If such a system exists, does this fact have any implication on its quantum version?

Comment: double pendulum

Comment: Two harmonic oscillators with frequencies $\omega_1, \omega_2$ such that $\omega_1/\omega_2$ is not a rational number.

Comment: @ Sean D   Any reason?

Comment: Although if either oscillator begins at equilibrium and at rest, $x_1(0) = \dot{x}_1(0) = 0$, one will have a periodic trajectory. But for almost all initial conditions, the motion will not be period.

Comment: A free particle does not have periodic orbit.

Comment: ... apart from the special case where the free particle is at rest.